# Explaining some details about String

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

Hi y'all I have a very simple question. I am studying different websites that talk about arrays and I see this part which I don't understand very well.

In the (1) Why does the '`myString.length()`' has a '`()`', why not just myString.length as in the example (2)??

In the (1) Why does the '`System.out.println(myString.substring(i,i+1))`' has '`myString.substring(i,i+1)`' why not just '`myString(i,i+1)`' ??

In the (1) Why does the '`System.out.println(myString.substring(i,i+1))`' has two values '`(i,i+1)`' why not just '`System.out.println(myString.substring(i))`' as in example (2)??

```
1. String myString="abcedaslkhldfag";
for(int i=0; i<myString.length(); i++)
System.out.println(myString.substring(i,i+1));  


2. for(int i=0; i<anArrayOfints.length; i++){
System.out.println(anArrayOfints[i]);
}
```

Thank you
I found it in this website http://www.javaclass.info/classes/java-array/array-examples-demonstration-and-code-snippets.php

Comment: Nice question, bit difficult to explain. Deep basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First*, about Arrays and Strings.

You are comparing totally different classes.

Array types are special objects that are dynamically created. Even array of primitives are objects (unlike in C) so it might have certain member variables/methods.
Have a look here: [Array members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7)

String is a class which encapsulates behavior suitable for strings, such as substring, trim etc. The actual data is stored internally as a character array, so there is a close connection between them, but the class itself represents more than just the characters.

*Secondly*, about subString method.

Methods called on a string object follow the syntax as specified by the API.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
public String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)
```

Have a look at the String API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You will find there a length() method that returns the length of the String.

A note about "Arrays" class.

There is a class called "Arrays" that became available as part of the collections framework. The purpose of this class was to include behaviors that where commonly used on all types of arrays(such as sorting and searching).

Comment: Ok this comment is good, a lot of information in these lines. I read it, I understand a lot better. Thank you Sr.

Answer (score 0):

The Array class extends java.lang.Object. Therefore array is an instance of Object. Arrays have one instance variable called length. It's a variable so you dont need the ().
And the string class has a member function called length, which is why you need the ().

Comment: Thank you Sr. very simple for someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `length()` is a method on the String class, while `length` is an instance variable on the `Array` class.

As for `myString.substring(i, i + 1)`, this is a method being called on an instance of the `String` class, which will return a new `String` instance containing the substring.  In fact, `myString.substring(i)` does exist in the API, and would return the substring that starts at `i` and ends with the last character in `myString`.

Note that `anArrayOfints[i]` returns the int stored at element `i` in the array.

Comment: After reading all comments and links this part didn't know it "myString.substring(i) does exist in the API, and would return the substring that starts at i and ends with the last character in myString". Thank you for your help and time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, `myString` is a string, which is an object. You are calling a method called `length()` of type String to know the length of the string. This method calculates the number of chars in the string and returns that number. And `subString()` is also a method that takes two parameters, begin and end index. This is just standard that is created by Java. To know more about the string methods, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

The second one is continuous memory of data, an array. The length of the array is also stored in the array and is accessed using '`.length`'

Comment: Thank you, very simple and clear explanation for guys like me.

Answer (score 0):

1, myString has a method named length. When use a method, you must specific the arguments which should be included in "()". In the (2), length means an attribute. Just use it as a variable.

2, substring is method. When use a method of some object, you can imagine you are sending command to this object. myString can not understand "myString(i,i+1)". You should specific the method or the command "subString"

3, anArrayOfints is an array object. Just like a list of something. You should specific a number to pick a element up.

Comment: Thank you Mr. I appreciate your response, confirms what I have learned.